Facing java.lang.IllegalStateException while rendering JSF Enterprise application in jboss 7.3 which uses jsf 2.3
Facing java.lang.IllegalStateException while rendering JSF Enterprise application in jboss 7.3 which uses jsf 2.3. Application was working fine with Jboss EAP 6.4 and after migration to Jboss EAP 7.3 getting below exception while loading UI screen and UI Componenets. Screen is loaded but UI components like autocomplete suggestions are not loaded as expected. We are using primeface library for UI components
exact stact trace originating as below
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:692)
at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getAttributes(FacesContextImpl.java:219)

could you please help me to fix the issue ?.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
